# in visual studio solution, how can I use exe built in one project in another project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, reference

In Visual Studio, I have a solution that includes multiple projects.  One of the projects is a code generator that creates a executable.  I want to use that executable in the same solution for another project that will use that executable in a custom build step to generate c++ code.

I thought I could use a reference but I cannot see how to specify the executable in the custom build using that reference.  Is a reference really used just for linking against?

Is the only way to use the executable to create a Post-Build step in the one project and move that executable to a known location in the solution and call that out in the other project?